# Creating amazon private url in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, amazon-s3

I am developing a project using zend framework. This project use amazon service for images and videos. To access all private images & videos I used signed url, Now my problem is this when I accessing these images or videos in my project its by default create 0 size images with the same name in to the root directory of amazon AWS account.

Please help me how I can over come this problem.

Comment: You need to clarify. For one thing there is no 'root directory' for an AWS account. I think that you have a bucket.

Comment: So whenever you are requesting an image amazon is creating an image with the same name but with 0 size????

Comment: Hi...dm03514 and Tom Anderson 
        Thanks for making interest in my question. As I discuss on the question. Yes when i make a requesting an image its creating a 0 size image. I want to is there any way to over come with this problem.